# How to add images when using spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a beginner at using Android Studio Java, I have been assigned to make a dropdown list with all the car names. I have to include 30 car images but to start things off I am trying to include 5 images, I have been trying to add an image on each of the cars that are on the dropdown list. I figured out how to do the spinner and I have the code for it but now when I click on the dropdown list and click the Ford car and I want the images to appear as well.

For the main.java (called Activity2.java) here is the code for it

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
private Spinner carsSpinner;
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

    carsSpinner = findViewById(R.id.carsSpinner);

    //final ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<>();
   // cars.add("Audi");
   // cars.add("Bentley");
   // cars.add("BMW");
   // cars.add("Chevrolet");
    //cars.add("Citroen");

    //ArrayAdapter<String> carsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, 
  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cars);

    //carsSpinner.setAdapter(carsAdapter);//

    carsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, carsSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString() + " Selected", 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

For the main activity.xml (called activity2.xml) here is the code for it, I know I have to include the ImageView there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/carsSpinner"
    android:entries="@array/cars"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

For the string.xml here is the code for it

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">My Application</string>
<string-array name="cars">
    <item>Audi</item>
    <item>Bentley</item>
    <item>BMW</item>
    <item>Ferrari</item>
    <item>Citroen</item>
</string-array>
```

This is how my application is looking but now I want to include the car image for each car on it, it will mean a lot if you guys could show me through the right direction.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a custom layout and adapter.

More information on how to implement it on the link below:

https://www.codingdemos.com/android-custom-spinner-images-text/